# API violation - multiple calls made to -[XCTestExpectation fulfill], How can i solve this problem

Tags: ios, xctest, xctestcase, xctestexpectation, quick-nimble

I'm writing unit test for my codes which using Combine framework

i have a async operation, so i use `expectation(descrption:)` to wait async operation

this is my code example

```swift
class MyViewModel {
  private var someOtherSubject: CurrentValueSubject<...>(...)
  var someOtherStream: ... { 
    return someOtherSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
  
  init(...) { 
    .
    .
    bind()
  }

  private func bind() { 
    . 
    .
    .
    someOfMySubject
      .flatMap { someAsyncOperation }
      .sink { [weak self] ... in 
         self?.someOtherSubject.send(value2)
      }
      .store(..)
  }

  .
  .

  func handleSomeUserAction() {
    self.someOtherSubject.send(value1)
    self.someOfMySubject.send(someEvent)
  }
}
```

i'm trying to check value which emitted by `someOtherStream` when `handleSomeUserAction` is called

so i wrote test code like this

```swift
func test_handleSomeUserAction() { 
  // given 
  let expectation = expectation(description: "...")
  var result: ValueType?

  // when 
  sut.someOtherStream
    .dropFirst() // drop CurretValueSubject's default value
    .sink { 
      result = $0
      expectation.fulfill()
    }
    .store(...)
  sut.handleSomeUserAction()

  // then
  wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1.0)
  let unwrapped = try XCTUnwrap(result)
  XCTAssertEqual(unwrapped, value1)
}
```

i know `expectedFulfillmentCount` is 1 because it's default value is 1

but test is failed and Xcode show me this message

> API violation - multiple calls made to -[XCTestExpectation fulfill]

so i tried to debug, and i figured out `expectation.fulfill()` called twice despite of `expectedFulfillmentCount` is 1

and result is `value2` not `value1` that i expected

why this happend? i think async operation(`flatMap {...}`) is finished too fast and `fulfill` called twice.

i tried delay mock method but i think this is not the right solution

Comment: Please edit your question to include an appropriate [mcve]. There is a lot of omitted code in your current question. You don't even show where you call `fulfill`

Comment: @Paulw11 I added fulfill in my code. 

In that situation, if aync operation quit too fast, can fulfill method called twice

Comment: It's nothing to do with speed.  Your subscriber chain is being called twice.  Because you have a `CurrentValueSubject`. It will fire with the initial value and then fire when you update the value.

Comment: @Paulw11 so i dropped first element using dropFirst operator to get value that i want to receive

Comment: Use the debugger.  Set breakpoints or print the values you are receiving.  The code in your question is too complex and too reduced to follow what is happening.  Create a [mcve].  The chances are that in doing so you may well solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

You code is kind of strange. But it looks like you are sending two values to  `someOtherStream`. So it is expected that the sink is called twice.